# How to return object from ArrayList with parameter matching a field?

Tags: java, object, return

I want to return the object of the `Book` class whose field `bookTitle` matches the parameter `selection`.

`BookList` is an `ArrayList` in the `Book` class containing all book objects.

With below code my IDE tells me `null`. How should the return statement actually be formulated?

```
public Book getBook(String selection) {
    for (Book book : Book.BookList) {
        if (selection.equals(Book.getBookTitle())) {
            return book;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IDE is also telling you that you're missing a return statement.  More to the point, is `getBookTitle` a static method, or a method to be invoked on each instance of `book`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class name instead of the variable name in your method. If you switch your loop to:

```
Book found = null;
    for (Book book : Book.BookList)
      {
                    if (selection.equals(book.getBookTitle()))
                    {
                       found =  book;
                    }
      }
return found;
```

Try this out, it should fix your problem.

Comment: We don't quite know enough about the problem to really be sure that this is the issue.  Further, you don't fix the issue where there's no return statement if the list doesn't contain the book list.

Comment: I took the return in loop out, and if he is getting the correct arrayList, then would this solve the problem since he is not actually looking at the individual book titles  in the arrayList of his original loop?

Comment: This would solve the problem since, if there are no book titles that equal `selection` verbatim, we would still return `null`.  It's not ideal to return `null`, but we'd still be returning something, which would satisfy the compiler.